# A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'File'

Tags: powershell

Power shell script (delete old backup files)

```
$date = (get-date).AddDays(-10)
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\\sc-sqlbackups\sqlbackups\SA144\Milli\teste" -Files | ?{$_.LastWriteTime -lt $date}
foreach ($file in $files) {
Write-Host "Removing $file"
$file | Remove-Item  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

the above command runs without an issue in Windows powershell(Windows 10). But when I create a  SQL Server job with the same command I get the

ERROR

> A job step received an error at line 2 in a PowerShell script. 
>   The corresponding line is
>
> '$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\sc-sqlbackups\sqlbackups\SA144\Milli\teste" -File | ?{$_.LastWriteTime -lt $date}  '. Correct the script and reschedule the job. The error information returned by PowerShell is: 'A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'File'.

Comment: What powershell version is this? It is possible the `-file` parameter was not available in versions prior to v3

Comment: Change the triple backslash into two backslashes. `-Files` should be `-File`, but you need PowerShell 3.0 or better for that.

Answer (score 0):

`-Files` is not support in old PS Verisons.
use `Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -eq $false }` Instead!